# Imprimir no início da página

Tags: php

Fiz um sistema de questões de vestibular, o usuário cria a lista de exercícios dele, responde e obtêm a nota, só que eu queria imprimir essa nota antes das questões minha página é mais ou menos assim como o código abaixo.

```
<NAV BAR / CABEÇALHO>

function resultado ($nota) {
    echo "Sua nota foi tal:".$nota;
}

<PROCESSAMENTO DA NOTA>

<CHAMA DA FUNCAO PARA IMPRIMIR>
```

Só que sempre imprime no local onde eu chamei a função, não onde ela está. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Está chamando a função onde?

Comment: Sei lá, num sei nem pq respondi, não entendi sua pergunta....

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente, você precisa fazer a função retornar um valor e dar o echo fora dela.

```
function resultado ($nota) {
    return "Sua nota foi tal: ".$nota;
}

echo resultado(0); // imprime : 'Sua nota foi tal: 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom pelo que entendi seria algo assim, coloca onde quiser:

```
<?php resultado(0);?></br>
<NAV BAR / CABEÇALHO>
<?php resultado(2);?></br>
<?php
function resultado ($nota) {
    echo "Sua nota foi tal:".$nota;
}
?>
<?php resultado(4);?></br>
<PROCESSAMENTO DA NOTA>
<?php resultado(7);?></br>
<CHAMA DA FUNCAO PARA IMPRIMIR>
<?php
resultado(10);
?>
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/bcJGd1)

Ou

```
<?php
resultado(0);
echo "<NAV BAR / CABEÇALHO>";
resultado(2);
function resultado($nota)
{   echo "\n"."Sua nota foi tal:".$nota."\n";
}
resultado(4);
echo "<PROCESSAMENTO DA NOTA>";
resultado(7);
echo "<CHAMA DA FUNCAO PARA IMPRIMIR>";
resultado(10);
?>
```

[Veja](https://ideone.com/fR4lrB)

Answer (score 0):

Se ela aparece somente onde chama, você pode tentar fazer uma gambiarra para chama-la de maneira indireta.

```
<NAV BAR / CABEÇALHO>

function resultado ($nota) {
    echo "Sua nota foi tal:".$nota;
}

function chamaresultado(){
    resultado();
}

<PROCESSAMENTO DA NOTA>

<CHAMA DA FUNCAO PARA IMPRIMIR> //chamaresultado();
```